# Painfully Slow JVM Not Caused by Memory Leak?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-leaks, jvm

I'm programming in Java using eclipse and after running JVM for a couple of hours, my program tends to slow to a trickle. What's normally printed (or executed) in a few fraction's of a second, is taking a couple of minutes or hours.

I'm aware this is usually caused by a memory leak in program. However, I'm under the impression that a memory leak slows PC bec it uses the majority of CPU power for garbage collection. When I take a look at task manager I only see 22-25% of CPU being used at the moment (it has remained steady for the last couple of hours) and approx. 35% of memory free on my machine.

Could the slowing down of my program be caused by something other than a memory leak or is it for sure a memory leak (which means I now need to take a hard look to track down source of leak..) And if yes, why would CPU usage be relatively low?

Thanks

Comment: It could be lots of stuff. Maybe a data structure that keeps growing in size, but doesn't scale well? Have you looked up how to run a Java profiler? That should be your first step. Check out visualvm, which comes with the jdk.

Comment: @yshavit ya I did use some profilers in the past. But I have a very difficult time interpreting what I see in a meaningful way. I mean, I see the number of objects and memory being used by those objects but it doesn't provide me with a clue about what part of code is responsible for creating those objects..  At any rate, if what I'm describing is actually a memory leak, wouldn't this result in extremely high CPU usage? If there's ample CPU available why would it take so long to print or execute action? Thanks

Comment: It's very hard to say without details, unfortunately. High GC would take up CPU, but it wouldn't be reported within a profiler. I would actually look at the CPU profile in VisualVM, not object/memory profiler -- be sure to use the sample mode, not trace, because trace is very slow. Hopefully that will give you a sense of where in the code the slowdown is. If there's not a culprit, it may be GC -- but I would start with the simpler assumption, which is that there's just some slow function in your code. But as written, this question is too broad to really answer well in this site's format.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens when you have loop relationships over your objects or entities. JVM tries to read the data or bind the data looping through same set of objects, this drastically effect the performance of the JVM; most of the time crash the application even. As on previous answer, you can use jconsole to check which time this happens and take an action. Hope you get the idea; may be this is not the case, this is what came to my mind when I read your question.

cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first, Memory Leak/any other malfunction doesn't affect your PC or any other part of your computer unless you are referencing some external resource which is choking. To answer your question, Generically speaking, while there is a possibility that slowing down your program could be caused by CPU, in your case however since your program/process is going slow gradually, most likely there is a memory Leak in your code.

You could use any profiler / jVIsualVM to monitor the mermoy usage/ object's state to nail down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may be aware that a modern computer system has more than one CPU core. A single threaded program will use only a single core, which is consistent with task manager reporting an overall cpu usage of 25% (1 core fully loaded, 3 cores idle = 25% total cpu capacity used).

Garbage collection can cause slowdowns, but usually only does so if the JVM is memory constrained. To verify whether it is garbage collection, you can use jconsole or jvisualvm (which are part of the JDK) to see how much CPU time was spent doing garbage collection.

To investigate why your program is slow, using a profiler is usually the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think We can not say anything straight forward for this issue. You need to check the behaviour of you program using  jconsole or jvisualvm which is part of you JDK.